# How to INSERT with cumulative add from a previous row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the following table

```
----------------------------
|  id  |    day   | count  |
----------------------------
    1   2013-01-01    10
    1   2013-01-05    20
    1   2013-01-08    45
```

the second and third row the count column is cumulative i.e. 20 = (10 from first row + 10 additional count) and 45 ( 20 from second row + 25 additional count). How can the second and third rows (and further) be inserted with cumulative add in Postgresql ?

Note: The additional count is read from a variable in a program. So the aim is to store this value in the 'count' column in Postgresql, but also add it with the 'count' found by last entry in ascending date order.

Comment: Where did you take the _additional count_ from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is how the insert statement with a select could look like:

```
insert into x(id, day, count) 
select 1, current_timestamp, 
coalesce((select max(count) from x), 0) + 10;
```

But this is not necessarily the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't say where does the *additional count* come from I assume there is an *additional count* column:

```
select *,
    sum(additional_count) over(order by "day")  "count"
from t
order by "day"
```

The `sum` function as a window function does a running total. It is a window function when it uses the `over` clause.